# testNG: customize test name within created report

Tags: webdriver, testng

Is it possible ( of course it is) and how to customize the test name displayed in the report?
For example, I have a login test that run 4 times ( 4 different browsers) but reported test name is always login.
I'd like to attach the browser at the end , to see something like login_FF,login_IE,.....
Any idea?
I use testNG!

Answer (score 0):

TestNG does provide options to customize the reporting, refer their site directly. But it does involve pretty good amount of effort........

Answer (score 0):

If you test extends ITest you can set it there. Here is an example I'm currently using:

```
private final ThreadLocal<String> testName = new ThreadLocal<>();
...

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
  public void prepare(Method method, Object[] testData) {
    if (testData == null || testData.length == 0) {
      testName.set(String.format("%s.%s", getClass().getSimpleName(), method.getName()));
    } else {
      testName.set(
          String.format(
              "%s.%s %s", getClass().getSimpleName(), method.getName(), Arrays.toString(testData)));
    }
}
```